# Best practice in HTML? How to delete table entry by submit?

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I would like to implement a table with a button in each row to delete that row.
Now I'm asking myself what is the best way to do that.

By the way I'm using JSPs with Spring tags but I think this is a common html question.

In my opinion I have two options: Using links or using buttons with forms

Link example (Delete users):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete Button</th>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="users">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:url value="/users/${user.userId}/delete" var="deleteUrl" />
                <a href="${deleteUrl}"><icon:delete/></a>
            </td>
            <td>${user.userId}</td>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Yes, this should work, but the URL to delete an entry is exposed directly in the browser. Not very save...

Button with from example (Delete users):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Delete Button</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="users">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:form action="/users/${user.userId}/delete" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit"><icon:delete/></button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
                <td>${user.userId}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This should work as well, but you have one form tag per button. And the URL to delete an entry is maybe exposed after submit in the browser url bar. 
Not the best way too...

So, what do you think is the best way? Or are there any other which are maybe better?

Comment: And exposing the URL is an isuse because? It is exposed nonetheless, even if you use AJAX it is fairly simple to retrieve the URL. What you want is the form with the URL, and you might want to use a DELETE in a hidden field (s o you can use a DELETE method instead of POST). And finally you want to add a CSRF token so only authorized and authenticated users can use the delete functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a GET request (i.e. a link) to delete data on the server. I remember a famous story (not sure if it was a HOAX or not) that overnight all data was deleted, the reason being that Google indexed the site and followed all the links...

You want to use the form way and probably want to use a DELETE request, in spring you can can configure the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, then when adding a hidden field named `_method` with the value `DELETE`.

Next you want to add a [CSRF token](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) to your form to make sure only authenticated (and authorized!) users can use a delete. Assuming you are using [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token) (or going to add) your final form should look something like this.

```
<form:form action="/users/${user.userId}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit"><icon:delete/></button>
</form:form>
```

In your controller you should have an `@DeleteMapping` for the URL.

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}") 
public void remove(@PathVariable("id") Long uid) { ... }
```